# Copy string from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, string, uiwebview, copy

I've put UIWebView in my app which loads login page, after user logs in, can I write some function that will copy specific link from that UIWebView that is specific for every user?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would probably be to include a JavaScript function in the page that returns the link or data you need. See [UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]

Another way could be to retrieve the HTML in your iOS code, get the data you need, and then set that content in the UIWebView using the loadHTMLString:baseURL: method.

Comment: I've searched for examples of logging in php site through code, but non of them works, I was thinking about logging in, and then load data with NSUrlConnection and then find string which needs to be copied, but I'm having problems with logging in...